# Checklist - web application security by authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, security, authentication

Just to ensure I have well made my homeworks, what best than confront my results with the community appreciation, hope it will help other people wondering how to securize their website.

I'm builting website with NodeJS and ReactJS on basis of an Express framework. My database stack is MongoDB and Mongoose. Very common stack for modern webapp in other words. So I have made some researches to understand what are the treats to prevent in order to secure my web application.

Here the treats I have spotted :

- XRF > synchronizer tokens,
- XSS > httpOnly cookies
- man in the middle, session hijacking > TLS / secure cookie flag
- brute force, time attack > Bcrypt slow CPU core time hashing
- rainbow table > salting the password, meaning put random data that is used as an additional input to a one-way function that "hashes"

In order to consolidate the security measures, available to make some counter-verification on the server's side - IP adress, location, this kind of stuff.

Other treats, less significant for a webapp but I put them here to flag them :

- beast
- squils
- SSLStrip

I am forgetting other threats very important to handling on concerning my webapp security ?

Any hint would be great,
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OWASP Top 10 list](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_Top_10) is a great read to get you started on application security.

The [OWASP Cheat Sheet Series](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Cheat_Sheet_Series) provides in-depth details on how to mitigate threats.

You're specifically asking about website security. Security is a layered approach, meaning if one layer fails to catch a security vulnerability, hopefully the next layer will catch it. It's fair to say that the industry agrees that a strong Content-Security-Policy is one of the more important things you can do to protect your website from XSS attacks.

There is no silver bullet in security.